# How do you send ␄ (EOT) to PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I accidently typed two commas instead of two periods and insanity pursued. How do I send EOT and stop whatever this double left-arrow bracket prompt (>).

```
PS C:\dbsync> cd ,,
>> q
>> exit
>> '
>> ,
>>
>>
>> ^D^D
>> ^X
>> ^Z
>> ^A
>>
>> ^Q
>> ^E^R
>> ,
>> ,
>> ,
>> ,,,,,
>> ]}}}
>> ;
>> '
```

[Wikipedia says to use <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character), but it didn't work as evidenced by the `^Z` above.
How do I stop this craziness?

This is PowerShell v2.0.-1.-1:

```
PS C:\> $Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't have the same result as you. Can you provide more information?

Comment: @JayBazuzi are you in powershell or cmd?

Comment: I was in PowerShell. See http://www.evernote.com/shard/s265/sh/482e7270-1210-4e0f-930e-ed8fa566e16d/bf0f506ed5afb36c43e9f2c013e94182

Comment: I used PowerShell v3.0. Which version do you have? (`$Host.Version`)

Comment: @JayBazuzi PowerShell v2.0.-1.-1

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to send EOT (or it just kills the process accepting input, not sure how it works).

Comment: It just kills the process. "EOF" is Ctrl+Z, although in your case PowerShell probably just ignores EOF and expects something different.

Comment: But not the parent process which in this case is the powershell console. So it is the right answer.

Comment: It might be the right answer to "how do you get out of `cd ,,`", but it's not the right answer to "how do you send EOT".